# Commutative ring with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm given the following question :

$\mathbb{Z} × \mathbb{Z}= \{(a,b) : a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers.
Prove that it is a commutative ring with unity.

I am able to prove that the set is closed under addition. But to prove this for multiplication, I arrive at : $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)$
How should I carry out this multiplication?

Comment: First you should think about how multiplication and addition can be defined.

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101030191126AAaiFuh&guccounter=1

Comment: Its component-wise.

Comment: You _do_ have an appropriate software to write it accurately, though; it is just done with pure text: `$\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$` gives $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$. For more information, you can check out [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Wuestenfux Since OP isn't you, how know it's componentwise? Or did you find a source for the problem?

Comment: Just a guess - canonical way.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for providing the link. I shall try to use this in future.

Answer (score 2):

Before saying a set is a ring, you have to specify the operations.

There are infinitely many ways to turn $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ into a commutative ring with unity, as well as infinitely many ways to turn it into a *noncommutative* ring with unity.

Here are three out of the infinitely many possibilities. In all cases, the addition is $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$.

1. $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,bd)$
2. $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,ad+bc)$
3. $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$